# SwiftUI change output format of `Text` using as `.timer`

Tags: swiftui, ios14, swiftui-text

Is there a way to change the output format of a `Text` using `init(_ date: Date, style: Text.DateStyle)`?

Using a `.timer`, the output is like: `0:42`, but I want something like `00:00:42`.

---

**Background**

I want to create a widget (iOS 14) where a timer is running, and as I think it's not a good idea to trigger a widget update every second, and this may even also not work reliably, at least that's not how widget are indented to be used.
So I thought about using this predefined timer functionality of `Text`.

I'm quite new to SwiftUI and don't really know about all the capabilities yet. So maybe I could create a similar custom Text-View by myself? Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Or asked differently: Is there a way to create such self-updating components by oneself, that also work in an iOS 14 widget? (Seems like using `Timer.publish` to update the View does not work in an iOS 14 widget)

Comment: did you figure this out?

Comment: I don't think this is (currently) possible. I just used a normal `Text` together with a timer to calculate the current offset from the reference date and trigger an update.

Comment: Can you maybe share your code on how you achieved this? I'm trying to achieve the same functionality

Comment: @Oscar I posted an answer below, on how I "solved" this.

Comment: Thanks for the help, as I turns out (and as you mentioned in your answer) this is impossible in the widget, thanks anyways though

Answer (score 0):

#### No solution => Workaround

As of today, there doesn't seem to be a proper solution for this. But as the interest in a "solution" or workaround for this seems to be there, I'll just post what I ended up with, for now.

#### Code

Basically I just manually update the `Text` once a second, and calculate the difference from the reference date to "now".

```
struct SomeView: View {
    let referenceDate = Date() // <- Put your start date here

    @State var duration: Int = 0
    let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .current, in: .common).autoconnect()
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(self.duration.formatted(allowedUnits: [.hour, .minute, .second]) ?? "")
            .onReceive(self.timer) { _ in
                self.duration = referenceDate.durationToNow ?? 0
            }

    }
}

extension Date {
    var durationToNow: Int? {
        return Calendar.current
            .dateComponents([.second], from: self, to: Date())
            .second
    }
}

extension Int {
    func formatted(allowedUnits: NSCalendar.Unit = [.hour, .minute]) -> String? {
        let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
        formatter.allowedUnits = allowedUnits
        formatter.zeroFormattingBehavior = .pad
        return formatter.string(from: DateComponents(second: self))
    }
}
```

#### WidgetKit limitations

This unfortunately does not work for `WidgetKit`, as the timer does not run or at least the UI does not refresh. So I ended up, only displaying minutes in the widget (which is kinda ok for my purpose) and just set an update in the "timeline" for each minute.

Comment: I am trying to create a clock widget and having hour and minutes is enough for me and I think your solution would be really good but I can't make it work with the code above, would you please share the code to achieve this (hours and minutes) for widgetKit?