# Change SwiftUI Text .timer format

Tags: swift, swiftui, ios14, widgetkit

I am trying to create a Widget with SwiftUI, and I want to use the ".timer" style from Text
but the result of the `Text(entry.date, style: .timer)`
is something like `15:34:23`

But I want the hour and minute part separately.

How can I achieve this?

I tried to get the string value of the text and format it in a method but It seems that there is no way to get Text String like we could do in Swift like `someLabel.text`

I also have found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63534579/swiftui-change-output-format-of-text-using-as-timer) that is similar to mine but I couldn't find any answer there

And I don't want to use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64053733/updating-time-text-label-each-minute-in-widgetkit) either, because it takes a lot longer to load the widgets.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Updating time text label each minute in WidgetKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64053733/updating-time-text-label-each-minute-in-widgetkit)

Comment: Actually, I don't wanna use that solution because it takes a lot longer for the widget to be loaded this way. it works for simple widgets but my widget is a little bit complicated, with this solution it can take more than a few minutes to load but with the .timer method, it is instant because there is no need to add 60 * 24 entires in advance

Comment: You can't change the `.timer` format, so you may need to create entries in advance.

Comment: Is there any way to get the Text string as we could do in Swift like someLabel.text?

Comment: No. And the problem here is that Widget views are *static*. You can't refresh them from inside the view itself. You need to reload the timeline. If you don't want to create entries for the whole day (as you say it's slow), you can create them for an hour only and reload after.

Comment: I tried that solution but after an hour, when it tries to get new timeline entries it doesn't do it right away and has some delays, do you happen to experience this too?

Comment: This answer might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64014799/8697793

Answer (score 1):

```
Text(Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: Date()), style: .timer)
```

But the hour is not displayed at 0 o'clock, and only one-digit hour is displayed before 10 o'clock.

Comment: But I just want to grab the minute part of it

Comment: My question was how to change the format but it is still showing the original format of hh:mm:ss

Comment: My code is to display the hour:minute:second between the current time and 0 points. For example, if the current time is 10:20 in the morning, then the distance from 0 is 10 hours and 20 minutes. The format is the default HH:mm:ss and cannot be modified.