# WidgetKit: .timer Text style expands it to fill the width, instead of taking space to fit the contained string

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, widgetkit

.timer Text style expands it to fill the width, instead of taking space to fit the contained string. Is there a way to change this behavior?

```
Text(entry.timeFinished, style: .timer).multilineTextAlignment(.leading).opacity(0.5).background(Color.red)
```

[image]

```
Text("3:41").opacity(0.5).background(Color.blue)
```

[image]

Entire View:

```
struct TimePieceWidgetEntryView: View {
    
    var entry: Provider.Entry
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Timer ⏱")
            Text(Date().addingTimeInterval(600), style: .timer).opacity(0.5)
        }.font(.title.bold().monospacedDigit())
        .padding(5)
        .widgetURL(entry.url)
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Having the same problem :(

Comment: Add your `body` code. By what you provided now, it works correctly if copied and pasted in the body as a standalone component.

Comment: @TomasJablonskis edited and added it to the original post.

Comment: It works correctly with both of your examples and with your provided body... Create new project and paste your body inside of clean `ContentView`, you will see.

Comment: Provide `body` of the view which is using `TimePieceWidgetEntryView `

Comment: @TomasJablonskis it does indeed behave as expected inside of an app, but not in a widget.

Comment: try to create formatted instead of style: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63950738/14733292

Comment: Still no solution on this issue?

Comment: Having same issue in live activity in Dynamic Island just taking all the space...

Comment: This is still an issue for me when using Dynamic Islands

Answer (score 3):

I have zero insight into how Apple is building Live Activities and widgets. My guess is that the widget is rendered and then cached. That is why things like standard timers/publishers don't update the UI. My guess is that these Text timers fill the space so that Apple can render a label on top of the cached view without requiring a new layout from the widget when the text size changes. I am saying this because I think the filling of the container is a feature and not a bug, so it probably won't change any time soon.

To get around this I force the size of the Text view to be the largest it should be. There are still some issues, however for the most part this solution looks ok.

```
struct TextTimer: View {
    // Return the largest width string for a time interval
    private static func maxStringFor(_ time: TimeInterval) -> String {
        if time < 600 { // 9:99
            return "0:00"
        }
        
        if time < 3600 { // 59:59
            return "00:00"
        }
        
        if time < 36000 { // 9:59:59
            return "0:00:00"
        }
        
        return "00:00:00"// 99:59:59
    }
    init(_ date: Date, font: UIFont, width: CGFloat? = nil) {
        self.date = date
        self.font = font
        if let width {
            self.width = width
        } else {
            let fontAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: font]
            let time = date.timeIntervalSinceNow
            let maxString = Self.maxStringFor(time)
            self.width = (maxString as NSString).size(withAttributes: fontAttributes).width
        }
    }
    
    let date: Date
    let font: UIFont
    let width: CGFloat
    var body: some View {
        Text(timerInterval: Date.now...date)
            .font(Font(font))
            .frame(width: width > 0 ? width : nil)
            .minimumScaleFactor(0.5)
            .lineLimit(1)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my "solution" to this issue. Not perfect but maybe it helps someone

```
Text(timerInterval: dateRange, countsDown: false)
  .monospacedDigit()
  .frame(width: 40)
```

Answer (score 0):

Apple still didn't fix it.

I have remade @datinc answer and made it more clearer and flexible to use for SwiftUI.

It will show only mm:ss format but you can easy to change the format you want.

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct TextTimer: View {

    let dateRange: ClosedRange<Date>
    let font: UIFont
    let width: CGFloat

    init(_ dateRange: ClosedRange<Date>, font: UIFont, width: CGFloat? = nil) {
        self.dateRange = dateRange
        self.font = font
        self.width = width ?? TextTimer.defaultWidth(font: font, dateRange: dateRange)
    }

    var body: some View {
        Text(timerInterval: dateRange, showsHours: false)
            .font(Font(font))
            .frame(width: width > 0 ? width : nil)
            .minimumScaleFactor(0.5)
            .lineLimit(1)
    }

    private static func defaultWidth(font: UIFont, dateRange: ClosedRange<Date>) -> CGFloat {
        let maxString = maxStringFor(dateRange: dateRange)
        let fontAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: font]
        return (maxString as NSString).size(withAttributes: fontAttributes).width
    }

    private static func maxStringFor(dateRange: ClosedRange<Date>) -> String {
        let duration = dateRange.upperBound.timeIntervalSince(dateRange.lowerBound)
        let minutes = Int(duration) / 60
        let seconds = Int(duration) % 60
        return String(format: "%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds)
    }

}
```